# sharepoint designer workflow does not start automatically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have created workflow for a list. When I select manual start in workflow setting, workflow work fine after manually doing it. But if I select "start workflow automatically when item get created and changed" , workflow does not start for list. If I go to list item and then workflow I can see that no workflow is associated with it. Please let me know what is the reason for this.

Comment: Does the list have any custom content type attached? If yes what is the default content type of that list?

Comment: Account are you using when testing this? If you are using the system account when testing, it does not start automatically. sharepoint\system.

Comment: Yes I am using system account, but using system account only i have created another workflow and it is starting automatically.

Content type is by default "item"

Comment: Good point @AndersAune. But why is that so? I haven't come across that information in any documentation.

Comment: @IbrahimDauda it's actually a change made back in 2009 I think :) _This problem occurs because a security fix in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 SP1 prevents declarative workflows from starting automatically under the system account._